# g++ compiler optimization

Tags: c++, optimization, g++

```
list<mpz_class> baseFactor;
```

1)

```
int *tab = new int [baseFactor.size()]; //baseFactor.size() ~= 20000
for(i = 0; i < baseFactor.size(); i++){
  cout << tab[i] << endl;
}

// Total time: 2.620790
```

2)

```
int size = baseFactor.size();
int *tab = new int [size]; //baseFactor.size() ~= 20000
for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
  cout << tab[i] << endl;
}

//Total time: 0.366500
```

Why the g++ compiler doesn't optimize code 1) in 2) ?

Comment: My guess is that in the first case the compiler doesn't know that the value returned by the `size()` function doesn't change, so it has to call it every loop.

Comment: how did you do the timing/profiling? if the cache is warm, then the second one will certainly speed up. also, check the generated ASM, you should see little to no change.

Comment: Have you turned on optimizations?

Comment: In #2, declare "size" as "const int" instead of just plain "int". And declare declare "i" as an inline var within the for loop as "for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){...}" and remove the local declaration of "i" where you are currently declaring it.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on where `baseFactor` is defined (global variable?), it can be difficult for the compiler to prove that `size()` always returns the same value.

If it cannot prove that, the call can not be moved out of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

For the first one to be optimised to the 2nd it would requre that baseFactor.size() never changes during the loop.

Of course it probably doesn't, but does the compiler know that?

Answer (score 1):

A `std::list` [container](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/) is a linked list, and computing its size may be costly (O(n) algorithm, that has changed in the latest C++11 standard IIRC). The compiler has no idea that the body of your function is not changing `basefactor`, so its size is computed once in every loop in the first case (at every test of the `for` loop) and only once in the second.

Maybe you should consider using `std::vector` instead.

Comment: So a `std::list` doesn't have a simple `size` member that it can return? That disappoints me.

Comment: I think it has changed in C++11, and because of that the new C++ standard library (binary) is not compatible with the old ones.

Comment: @MrLister - `std::list` has a `splice` function that moves nodes between different lists. In C++03 the choice was to have `splice` be constant time which required giving that up on `size`. I believe C++11 made a different choice - *some* calls to `splice` will take linear time.

Comment: @BoPersson: In C++11 (23.3.5.5 [list.ops]) `splice` is constant time apart from the `splice(const_iterator pos, list<>&&, const_iterator first, const_iterator last)` overload which is linear (unless it's a self-assignment in which case it is constant). Furthermore, `list` now fully support the Sequence requirements (no more special case). So yes, `size()` is now constant time for lists as well.